# getTransactionCount with 'pending' not working?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, bug, nonce

Sending Ethereum transactions requires incrementing the nonce properly. In a typical application, there can be concurrent and/or consecutive requests to transfer from the same address.

Most solutions I've seen use `getTransactionCount(fromAddress, 'pending')` to set the nonce of the transaction, which is then sent using `sendRawTransaction`.

If two requests happen in the same block, then `getTransactionCount(fromAddress, 'pending')` should increase between the requests. However, this doesn't seem to be the case:

```
> web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0xf82e...", "pending");
5
> web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: "0xf82...", to: "0xf1c...", value: 42000000000000000});
I0624 15:57:41.848826 eth/api.go:1193] Tx(0xbd094a59eb8f05653f35fa93a9254db95bc6b9b5bdd3b95aedda27bb781545f9) to: 0xf1c...
"0xbd094a59eb8f05653f35fa93a9254db95bc6b9b5bdd3b95aedda27bb781545f9"
> web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0xf82...", "pending");
5
> I0624 15:57:59.315075 miner/worker.go:337]   Mined block (#4529 / 7788e873). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0624 15:57:59.315639 miner/worker.go:555] commit new work on block 4530 with 1 txs & 0 uncles. Took 529.458µs
I0624 15:57:59.315664 miner/worker.go:433]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #4524
I0624 15:57:59.315989 miner/worker.go:555] commit new work on block 4530 with 1 txs & 0 uncles. Took 310.783µs
> web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0xf82...", "pending");
6
```

As you can see, `getTransactionCount(from, 'pending')` only increases after the block has been mined. In result, the second request uses the same nonce and the second transaction fails (queued, dropped, etc.).

Is this a bug with `getTransactionCount`? I'd assume it should return an increased nonce, because `'pending'` has been specified.

Also, do we need to manage the nonce on the application side or is the some other solution to this? A stateless solution on the application side would be much simpler to manage.

Comment: Same here. `getTransactionCount` with `pending` only increases when a block was mined for me. Smells like a bug and will investigate further.

Answer (score 6):

This is indeed a bug, as confirmed recently by members of the geth team. [Bug Report](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2880)

Until then, you will indeed need to manage nonce on the application side.

Answer (score 3):

The bug has been fixed in version 1.8.21

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/15794